# What is the best neural network type to classify time series

Tags: signal-analysis

I am a beginner in AI methods. I have a collection of x(t) data, where x are some signal amplitudes and t is a time. My testing data are divided into two classes, say those from good and bad experimental samples. I need to classify the signals from unknown samples as good or bad according to their similarity to these two classes. What kind of a neural network is the best in this case? Could you recommend me some example in the literature where such a problem is considered?

Comment: Usually, the type of classifier is determined by the parameters of the problem at hand. What parameters of the problem prompt you to want to use neural networks for this classification task? What does the feature space look like? What sort of features are you planning to use?

Comment: I do not know, in fact. There are sime differences in depth of the maxima, some difference in periods, some differences in slope at some regions. The problem is that the features are not clear and I hoped that neural network could allow me to skip the problems of classical mathematical analysis where one well known feature like a periodicity is taken into account and some more global and general differences in signal are found.

Comment: Is it reasonable to regard an each data point as an individual input neuron (about 2k points) and teach the network to give 0 (bad) or 1 (good) as an output?

Comment: All these things that you mention correspond to different aspects of time series characteristics. So, if you want to "catch" specific waveforms, you tune your features to be sensitive to those characteristics. Looking for "catch all" makes the question very wide. Perhaps start from speech recognition with MFCCs and a recurrent network (?). Or, maybe add some more detail to the question? In any case you can use the DSP.SE chat to better determine your question.